# Unique key constraint in sql server for new values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unique-constraint

I want to implement unique key constraint on my table for new values, previous data is duplicate
e.g

```
declare @temp table
(
id int identity,
PolicyNO varchar(30)
)
insert into @temp values('abc')
insert into @temp values('abc')
insert into @temp values('abc')
```

now I want to add a unique constraints on @temp table. The new record on id=3 or greater will have to be unique and here third record should be restricted for insertion

```
ALTER TABLE @TEMP   
ADD CONSTRAINT Unique_PolicyNo UNIQUE (PolicyNO ) where id>3
```

some thing like that I am facing trouble in syntax any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.temp 
(
id int identity,
PolicyNO varchar(30)
)
insert into  dbo.temp  values('abc')
insert into  dbo.temp  values('abc')
insert into  dbo.temp  values('abc')


CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX__tem] 
ON  dbo.temp  (PolicyNO)
WHERE id>3
```

Then try to insert one new value twice.

or

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX__tem] 
ON  dbo.temp  (PolicyNO)
WHERE id>3 AND PolicyNO IS NOT NULL
```

in order to allow insertion of `null` values.